# Renaming multiple files - corresponding to a list in file

Tags: command-line, bash

I am new learner of Linux - Ubuntu. I need to rename a large number of files (keeping same extension) corresponding to a list of names in a file. I have a list of names in a text file.

For example

Current filename   =>      New filename

GCA_001340506.1_ASM54621.fna  =>   wax.fna

GCF_0133435.1_ASM4354653.fna =>    strains2213.fna

I need to rename current filename with the new filename. As we can see, I need two things first to match the corresponding filename and then rename it.

I cannot find a proper way to complete this task. Kindly help me in this regard.

Awan

Comment: but the old filename and the new filename are both in the text file ?

Comment: @Furqan  Identical question appeard a few mins ago;  Such a coincidence! https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613880/rename-multiple-files-accordingly-with-names-list#613880

Comment: @Lews Yes both old and new filenames are present in the text file.

Comment: @WilliamMartens I don't know that person but I must appreciate he explained my query in a much better way.

Comment: @Furqan No I just wanted to link a very identical questions, Was not about if you or he knew each other :P Just trying to help //Wishes

Comment: @WilliamMartens Thanks. I am also surprised to see. Hopefully following solutions will help me that I am going to try.

Comment: @Furqan FINAL EDIT ,  can you please try my answer below (3rd Edit) Sorry for such A LONG post, Hope it works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following function.
you have to use in this way:

**$ furqan_mv filenames.txt**

the file filenames.txt must have the following format:

oldfile => newfile

the extension is always **fna**.
Here is the function:

```
furqan_mv() {
ext=".fna"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    oldfile=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
    newfile=`echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`
    mv $oldfile.$ext $newfile.$ext
done < $1
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgive my ignorance. I saved this function in a file with .sh extension. Am I correct? I am sure this function will also be working but more flexible then the another solution suggested. Please correct me how to save this function and with which extension?

Comment: no, you have to copy and paste the function directly on bash. But when you exit from the shell or reboot the pc you lose the function. If you want to keep it you can paste it on your ~/.bashrc file. Before to use it make a backup of the folder where you use it.

Answer (score 2):

If your file format is `source.fna => target.fna` you can use `mmv` to rename your files. By leaving out the `from` `to` arguments on the command-line, `mmv`  will take source-target pair, one per line,  on the standard input.

```
awk -F '=>' '{print $1 $2}' files.txt | mmv
```

`mmv` can actually handle this format directly, but it's more of a coincidence.

> mmv ignores lines on the standard input that look like its own error and "done" messages, as well as all
> lines beginning with white space, and will accept pattern pairs with or without the intervening "->" (or "-^", "=>", or "=^").

```
cat file.txt | mmv
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Askubuntu!

Would this work?

---

I took the names from this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613880/rename-multiple-files-accordingly-with-names-list#613880

since you don't include the contents of the file where the new filenames are

```
for file in *.fna;

 do
  read line;
   
   mv -v "${file}" "${line}"; done < names.txt
```

Test run outputs e.g files

- 1.pdf > Fabio.pdf

Comment: Sorry I just mentioned one more thing. How it would match the current filename with the new filename. I have a list of new names in a file. I must mention that each new file name is different.

Comment: Oh,  that's a bit more confusing, Okay working on it, :P   +Thanks for pointing the details out, it really helps and clarifies the goal

Comment: If you highlight all the files and right click and choose 'rename' you will be presented with a very useful batch filename editor that may be of use.

Comment: @Furqan I've updated the answer, is it satisfactory? (Added a very near identical reference to a stack overflow page)  //Wishes

Comment: @Furqan Finally Done with the script, can you tell me if it's working for you or not, When you're going to test it?  (If it's not working, explain what went wrong) //Regards   Will.

Comment: @WilliamMartens. Great work. Just need to take care of the sorting order of the files and it worked like magic.

Comment: @Furqan Thanks so much!  I appreciate it, really!  //Best wishes!

Comment: @Furqan For me It's good to know that it got answerd, but I hope my answer at least provided some insight about how it could* be done,  or is helpful for others.  //Cheers!     //Will